# What でな means here?

Tags: translation

> 使い方は実戦でな

It's from a video game "Final Fantasy X". At the beginning of the game Auron gives Tidus a sword and says this phrase before their first battle with enemies.

Is there some verb omitted between で and な, like 見て?

Or he just says,  "It's for use in the real battle"
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 使い方は実戦でな

This "sentence" is like the ones where we omit the verb and just use を at the end:

> 良い一日を

From the context, I would guess it means something like "*learn how to use it in a real battle*" where the verb "learn" is omitted. As for the で and the な, な is the 終助詞, and で is the 格助詞 so nothing special.

The full sentence could be:

> 使い方は実戦で身につけな